# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This source was already added with the different observer

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Can anyone please explain this expression properly for me... It seems to be the problem I'm facing currently.

[`MediatorLiveData#addSource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData)

> Starts to listen the given source LiveData, onChanged observer will be called when source value was changed.
>
> `onChanged` callback will be called only when this MediatorLiveData is active.
>
> If the given LiveData is already added as a source but with a different Observer, `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown.

I currently have the following as my ViewModel (Called `SplashViewModel`)

```
package com.testapp.testapp.ui.splash;

import com.testapp.testapp.repository.HealthTipRepository;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;


public class SplashViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final HealthTipRepository healthTipRepository;

    // Load Status will be used to fill up the progress bar inside the Activity
    private final MediatorLiveData<Integer> loadStatus = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    
    @Inject
    SplashViewModel(HealthTipRepository healthTipRepository) {
        this.healthTipRepository = healthTipRepository;
    }

    LiveData<Integer> observeLoadStatus() {
        loadStatus.addSource(healthTipRepository.createHealthTips(), healthTips -> {
            int currentValue = loadStatus.getValue();
            int newValue = currentValue != null ? currentValue + 25 : 25;
            loadStatus.setValue(newValue);
        });
    }
}
```

In the activity, I have this:

```
package com.testapp.testapp.ui.splash;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.testapp.testapp.R;
import com.testapp.testapp.storage.PrefManager;
import com.testapp.testapp.ui.BaseActivity;
import com.testapp.testapp.ui.FactoryViewModel;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import butterknife.BindView;

// Base Activity has already injected the Dagger component
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.splash_progress)
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Inject
    FactoryViewModel factoryViewModel;
    private SplashViewModel viewModel;

    // PrefManager is responsible for managing shared preferences. It exposes a .get Method
    @Inject
    PrefManager prefManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factoryViewModel).get(SplashViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Performs checks to turn on location. The viewmodel is placed in the
        // onREsume to ensure that even when we leave the activity to turn on the
        // location and return, we can always start the viewmodel
        boolean turnedOnLocation = false;
        if (!turnedOnLocation) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }

        boolean appSetup = prefManager.get("app_setup", false);
        if (!appSetup) {
            viewModel.observeLoadStatus().observe(this, status -> {
                progressBar.setProgress(status + "");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Everything runs as smoothly, however, when I leave this activity and return, the application crashes with the error:

```
Process: com.testapp.testapp, PID: 29865
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.testapp.testapp/com.testapp.testapp.ui.splash.SplashActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This source was already added with the different observer
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3609)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3649)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This source was already added with the different observer
    at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData.addSource(MediatorLiveData.java:89)
    at com.testapp.testapp.ui.splash.SplashViewModel.fetchSensorLocations(SplashViewModel.java:25)
    at com.testapp.testapp.ui.splash.SplashViewModel.observeLoadStatus(SplashViewModel.java:17)
    at com.testapp.testapp.ui.splash.SplashActivity.observeViewModels(SplashActivity.java:121)
    at com.testapp.testapp.ui.splash.SplashActivity.onResume(SplashActivity.java:77)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1355)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7138)
```

I will really appreciate an explanation and why I keep getting this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You are setting up **2** observers on the same source of the `MediatorLiveData`.

You **can only set 1 observer per source**, otherwise an `IllegalStateException` is thrown, just like in your case.

Move your `observe` method from `onResume()` to `onCreate()`.

A ViewModel does not get destroyed when you are putting your activity in the background. It is still in memory, waiting for the activity to return to the foreground. It only gets destroyed when the activity is completely closed.

If you want to **stop** observing a particular source, simply use `removeSource()`.

If you want to **start** observing the source again, use `addSource()`.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel B. My reason for placing the observer method in the onResume is that I perform checks to turn on location. Now if the user leaves the activity to the settings page to turn on location, he is brought back to the `onResume` method. And I will like to observe **only** when the location is turned on. I'll follow your advice but can you suggest a way to observe only when location is turned on...? Thanks

Comment: @cr05s19xx use `void removeSource (LiveData<S> toRemote)` to stop observing a source of the MediatorLiveData. Check if the location is turned off, if it is, remove the resource.

Comment: Can you please clarify? Using my example? Do I call the addSource and removeSource in the ViewModel or in the activity? thank you

Comment: @cr05s19xx You need to store your LiveData objects in the ViewModel. Then, you need to define methods that allow you to observe and stop observing, inside the ViewModel as well. In your Activity, when something happens and you want to stop observing, call the method to stop observing from the ViewModel. When you are ready to observe again, from the Activity, call the method from the ViewModel, that starts observing again.

Answer (score 0):

1.) you generally shouldn't EVER use `onResume` unless you are working with camera.

But if you do, then  you should use `observeForever` and `removeObserver` instead of `.observe(LifecycleOwner`.

2.) This

```
   // Load Status will be used to fill up the progress bar inside the Activity
    private final MediatorLiveData<Integer> loadStatus = new MediatorLiveData<>();

    @Inject
    SplashViewModel(HealthTipRepository healthTipRepository) {
        this.healthTipRepository = healthTipRepository;
    }

    LiveData<Integer> observeLoadStatus() {
        loadStatus.addSource(healthTipRepository.createHealthTips(), healthTips -> {
            int currentValue = loadStatus.getValue();
            int newValue = currentValue != null ? currentValue + 25 : 25;
            loadStatus.setValue(newValue);
        });
    }
}
```

should be

```
   // Load Status will be used to fill up the progress bar inside the Activity
    private final MediatorLiveData<Integer> loadStatus = new MediatorLiveData<>();

    {
        loadStatus.addSource(healthTipRepository.createHealthTips(), healthTips -> {
            int currentValue = loadStatus.getValue();
            int newValue = currentValue != null ? currentValue + 25 : 25;
            loadStatus.setValue(newValue);
        });
    }

    @Inject
    SplashViewModel(HealthTipRepository healthTipRepository) {
        this.healthTipRepository = healthTipRepository;
    }

    // LiveData<Integer> observeLoadStatus() {
    // 
    // }
}
```